# How to replace several different characters in text file using Asterisk in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, file, text, replace, asterisk

I try to delete from text file those characters '{a}' '{b}' ... and so on (I have 250 curly braces in the text file) using this code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1255 -*-
import sys,codecs,string

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
root = r"G:\desktop\y\test2.txt"
x = open(root)
s=x.read().replace('{*}','').replace('-','')
x.close()
x=open(root,"w")
x.write(s)
x.close
```

because the letters change in every curly brackets i used asterisk in the,

but after i run this code nothing change in the text file:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>>
```

i red:

- [Python: Replace multiple strings in text file with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057347/python-replace-multiple-strings-in-text-file-with-multiple-inputs)

but didn't found my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest, I believe, would be to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re

data = '''{a} Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, {b} a new nation, {c} conceived in Liberty, {d} and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'\{[A-Za-z]\}')

print(pattern.sub('{*}', data))
```